# Solving an SDE by using Ito's formula

Tags: stochastic-calculus, finance

I am having trouble starting this problem.

Consider the stochastic differential equation:

$$dX(t) = (1/4)dt + \sqrt{X(t)}dW(t) $$

1. Solve the equation by applying Ito’s lemma to the function $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$

Comment: @Canardini : I've found the first and second derivative of f(x) and I plugged it into Ito's lemma, and I got (1/2sqrtx) dX(t) + (-1/8)x^(-3/2)(dX(t))^2

Comment: Note that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = 0$, as $f$ doesn't have any time dependence.

Comment: @ToralPatel Instead of $x$ it should read $X(t)$ (e.g. $\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{X(t)}} \, dX_t$ is the first term). Now... you have to plug in $dX(t)$ and $(dX(t))^2$, right?

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: All three questions you asked so far are asking that we do your homework for you. Please adopt without delay a more constructive approach of the site.

Answer (score 2):

We have that

$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$f''(x)=-\frac{1}{4}x^{-\frac{3}{2}}$$

We define the process $Y_t=\sqrt{X_t}$, and we have 
$$dY_t=f'(X_t)dX_t+\frac{1}{2}f''(X_t)d\langle X,X\rangle_t$$

or 
$$dY_t=\frac{1}{2}{X_t}^{-\frac{1}{2}}dX_t-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{4}X_t^{-\frac{3}{2}}d\langle X,X\rangle_t$$
or
$$dY_t=\frac{1}{2}{X_t}^{-\frac{1}{2}}dX_t-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{4}{X_t}^{-\frac{3}{2}}(X_tdt)$$

Finally ,

$$dY_t={\frac{1}{2}{X_t}^{-\frac{1}{2}}dX_t-\frac{1}{8}{X_t}^{-\frac{1}{2}}}$$
$$={\frac{1}{2}{X_t}^{-\frac{1}{2}}((1/4)dt + \sqrt{X(t)}dW(t))-\frac{1}{8}{X_t}^{-\frac{1}{2}}}$$

We have $$Y_t=Y_0+\frac{1}{2}W_t$$

thus $$\sqrt{X(t)}=\sqrt{X(0)}+\frac{1}{2}W_t$$

Comment: Indeed ! Done , thanks!